# Simplify a given algebraic string. Output the simplified string without parentheses

Tags: java

The examples look like this, Input : "a-(b+c)" output "a-b-c", Input : "a-(a+b)" output "b"

I came up with this method, but the result for input: "a-(a+b)" is "a-a-b", which the correct one should be "b", how to improve that?

```
public String simplify(String str)  
{  
    int len = str.length();  
 
    char res[] = new char[len];  
    int index = 0, i = 0;  
  
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer> ();  
    s.push(0);  
  
     while (i < len) {  
        if (str.charAt(i) == '+') {  
  
            if (s.peek() == 1)  
                res[index++] = '-';  
  
            // If top is 0, append the same operator  
            if (s.peek() == 0)  
                res[index++] = '+';  
  
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == '-') {  
            if (s.peek() == 1)  
                res[index++] = '+';  
            else if (s.peek() == 0)  
                res[index++] = '-';  
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == '(' && i > 0) {  
            if (str.charAt(i - 1) == '-') {  
                // x is opposite to the top of stack  
                int x = (s.peek() == 1) ? 0 : 1;  
                s.push(x);  
            }  
  
            else if (str.charAt(i - 1) == '+')  
                s.push(s.peek());  
        }  
  
        else if (str.charAt(i) == ')')  
            s.pop();  
  
        else
            res[index++] = str.charAt(i);  
        i++;  
    }  
    return new String(res);  
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (ASTs)? It is like the best way to approach this.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, do we really need ASTs, can't just use stack?

Comment: You *could* use a stack, but think ahead for how to simplify more complex expressions. E.g. `a + (b - (2 * a + (c - d)) + c) - 2 * c`. You need the entire expression parsed into memory, then the ability to rearrange the expression, which is difficult to do with a stack. E.g. you flatten it (remove parenthesis) to `a + b - 2 * a - c + d + c - 2 * c`, rearrange it to `a - 2 * a + b - c + c - 2 * c + d`, and finally merge it to `-a + b - 2 * c + d`. It gets even more complicated if you begin multiplying variables, e.g. `a * (5 - b) - 7 * (b - 3 * (a + 4))`